# How to get advanced filter to refresh

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the advanced filter to get data to show in another sheet if one of the values meets a criteria.

This is basically working. But when a new row is added to the source data or if an existing value in the data is changed, then the filtered data does not change.

Is there a way to apply an advanced filter so that when new values are added or existing values change the filter applies to them as well.

These are the values going in the advanced filter..

```
>List Range  
  'Action Register'!$A$2:$M$243 

>Criteria Range 
  Sheet1!$B$1:$B$2  

>Copy to Range  
  $AD$35:$AI$67
```

Comment: Try using a table

Comment: Should I make the list range or the copy to range a table?

Comment: Both. Tables are one of the best Excel tools for making your life easy

Comment: Just made them both tables but they still don't update automatically